# Proveit.com C++ test

Tags: c++, testing

Has anyone taken the C++ test on proveit.com ? I've done it a few times, and there are always questions that I get wrong, but I can't help but assume it's the site and not me. The only example I can think of off the top of my head (its been a while) is

What is the value of `x` after the operation?

```
int x = 5;
++x;
```

And it gives a few answers, one of which being 6. I don't see how it could be anything but. Just to be sure I would compile the code and still get the same answer, but the test would tell me I'm wrong. Wondering if anyone has any experience with this test/site.

Comment: Do you recall what the other choices were?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with proveit.com,  If you really want to gauge your C++ knowledge try the quiz at: http://www.mycppquiz.com

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh: `Question #2: static member variables must be defined outside of the class for them to be used`. I would answer `false`, because a `static int const = 5;` allows to define the value right in the class, yet the site says this assertion is true. I'm unsure as to its quality (maybe I didn't understood fully...) :/

Comment: @Matthieu: Perhaps the latter is true.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the test read what will this output:

```
int x = 5;
std::cout << x++;
```

And the question was:

> What will be the output?

Because when you do this x will change value but will display 5 from cout because x is incremented after the original value of x is displayed. Otherwise, it should equal 6 in your case. (You said it had been a while...)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this is implementation dependent, because there might an overflow here. But for all practical purpose, yes, the value of `x` should be 6 when the code is done execution.

Comment: Maybe if your have a 3.4 bit integer? I don't think there is any possible binary architecture where 5+1 is an overflow...

Comment: @meagar that's why I said that practically it doesn't matter. But if we speak about _Standard C++_ then it is irrelevant what architectures exist and which don't.

Comment: @wilhelmtell You mean which kind of architectures exist and which **can't**. That kind of thinking is why C++0x is almost two years late. *"If we don't think about the architectures that cannot exist in our universe, who will?!"*

Comment: @meagar I'm not in the committee, but I take the suggestion as an overwhelming compliment. And that was a question from a test: I hate tests (not the `JMP` instruction kind), maybe because I all too often try to be correct irrespective of what the question poser expects. A rebel, you may say.

Comment: No. C++ standard defines the minimum range for a signed `int` to be from -32767 to 32767 so obviously a C++ int cannot overflow after 5.

Comment: @eq- where's that from? last time i checked the only size guarantee we had was that `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: as far as I can tell it isn't mentioned directly. But the standard does have a note regarding `int` sizes saying: `44) that is, large enough to contain any value in the range of INT_MIN and INT_MAX, as deﬁned in the header <climits>`. `INT_MIN` doesn't seem to be specified directly either, it is inherited from C. In ANSI C, `INT_MIN` has a maximum value of `-32768` and `INT_MAX` has a minimum value of `32767`. Therfore an `int` must have at least that range.

Comment: @Evan: footnote 39 mentions both INT_MIN and INT_MAX.

Comment: @meagar: what evidence do you have to support your claim about supporting nonexistent architectures? Perhaps you'd be so kind as to cite which meeting minutes you're going from here?

Comment: @Jerry: that is actually same note that I quoted, I was just citing the a working draft of c++0x, not 2003. It does not appear that `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX` are directly defined by the c++ standard though. Instead it just says `The contents are the same as the Standard C library header <limits.h>.`

Comment: @Evan: yes, that's true -- it leaves defining them to the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an answer by now, but hopefully this will help someone else. Depending on how the question is stated you may have got the wrong answer:

```
int x = 5;
cout << x++ << endl;
cout << x << endl;
```

would display 5 and 6 because x is incremented AFTER it has been outputted. However,

```
int x = 5;
cout << ++x << endl;
cout << x << endl;
```

would display 6 and 6 because x is incremented BEFORE it has been outputted.